# How do I not embed the SoundCloud player? I just want the link

Tags: embed

Just the title. I'd rather just post SoundCloud links but I can't disable embedding the player. Sorry if this was already posted; I really couldn't find this mentioned anywhere else :/ Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of posting the link on its own, go to the text/html view and paste it on its own and wrap it in anchor tags

Comment: Perfect!! Surround the links with <a> </a> and the players went away. Thanks, Tom!